# What is the difference between SonarQube 6.x version and SonarQube 5.5.x [LTS] versions.?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Could you please tell me  what is the difference between SonarQube 6.x version and SonarQube 5.5.x [LTS] versions.? Is SonarQube 6.x is free and SonarQube 5.5.x is licensed one?

Is latest C# plugin version 5.5.2 works only with SonarQube 5.6+ version ? or can work with SonarQube 6.x version ? If works for both then why it’s not mentioned here?

Answer (score 1):

Both versions of SonarQube are FLOSS (i.e. free). In fact, *all* versions of the SonarQube server are free. Marking a version LTS means that it is the "Long Term Support" version. Specifically, bug fix versions will be released, as necessary, as long as that version is the LTS version. Generally LTS's remain so for ~1 year. Then the LTS designation is moved to a new version and support for all previous versions is dropped.

If a plugin is marked compatible with x.y+, that means it's compatible with version x.y, AND with version x.(y+1), x.(y+2), ... and even with (x+1).0, (x+1).1, and so on. So yes, a plugin that is compatible with 5.6+ *is* compatible with 6.x versions.